# Unable to ssh back into rebooted EC2 instance when secondary EBS volume is attached

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm using an EC2 instance (Ubuntu 14.04 Community AMI) for a web app. I've noticed that if I do `sudo reboot`, I don't automatically logout of the system.

Next if I do `exit`, I exit the system.

But thereafter, I am unable to `ssh` back into it (ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused).

Note that stop/start from the EC2 dashboard doesn't have this problem. I.e. programmatic reboot produces the problem, dashboard stop/start doesn't.

But more significantly, if I  detach the secondary EBS; removing its config from `/etc/fstab`, rebooting works fine.

Have a look at the output of `ls -al /dev/disk/by-uuid/`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 80 Oct  4 18:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 80 Oct  4 18:40 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Oct  4 18:40 298fab5b-6c90-4394-a85f-f354eb045052 -> ../../xvda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct  4 18:40 5c3e50bb-61e9-4f11-acb4-f3efe31e985d -> ../../xvdb
```

And `/etc/fstab/`:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 0
UUID=5c3e50bb-61e9-4f11-acb4-f3efe31e985d       /home/ubuntu/data       ext4    defaults,nofail,nobootwait       0      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably hanging on unmounting that volume, or some similar problem. Have you looked at the console for this instance while rebooting, or looked at any logs it is configured to send? You're missing some significant messages if you don't.

Ultimately, problems like this often come down to the workload itself, rather than an AWS specific problem.

Comment: If I'm hanging while unmounting the volume, how would that affect ssh?

Comment: Because the SSH daemon will stop before volumes are unmounted. So there's a gap in shell access that can be corrected by viewing the console directly. Granted, with the information we have here I'm making an educated guess. But viewing the console during shutdown will probably tell you what the root problem is.

Comment: I found my redis instances were hanging. Thanks for guiding me where to look.